# How to prevent Hyperledger Composer app from loading Bootstrap?

Tags: node.js, angular, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I want to remove the Bootstrap stylesheet from my Hyperledger Composer-compiled project.

I compiled using `yo hyperledger-composer` then `npm start`. Whenever `src/index.html` gets served at http://localhost:4200/, a Twitter Bootstrap `<style>` tag is being inserted right before the closing `</head>` tag. Here is the source:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My App</title>
    <base href="/">

    <style type="text/css">/*!
     * Bootstrap v3.3.7 (http://getbootstrap.com)
     * Copyright 2011-2016 Twitter, Inc.
     * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)

                ...
                [bootstrap.min.css is being inserted here, I don't know why]
                ...

        /*# sourceMappingURL=bootstrap.min.css.map */
    </style>

    <style type="text/css">/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
    </style>
    <style></style>
    <style>{%BLOCK%}</style>
</head>
```

Where in my project do I look for the offending code? I want to remove this Bootstrap  tag altogether.

I grep'ed the /src/ directory, but "bootstrap" doesn't turn up any hits (besides `.bootstrapModule(AppModule);`.

In the root directory, it is listed as a dependency in `package.json` as `"bootstrap": "^3.3.7",`. Therefore, I think it is importing the style from `node_modules/bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.min.css`.

There is no .angular-cli.json file. We're not using ng-bootstrap, as far as I can tell. Where is this style injection coming from?

Comment: I'd expect you to have `ng-bootstrap` imported. https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started

Comment: thanks for the reply. I checked, I'm not loading NgbModule anywhere.

Comment: Styles added to Angular components get added as `<style>` tag in `<head>` (after being rewritten for style encapsulation). I don't know where it might come from in your case.

Comment: ok, I appreciate the suggestion

Comment: @DanSelman do you think this is a Hyperledger Composer issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, there is an .angular-cli.json file after all. You can remove it from the script loader there.